# How do I can assign every UserID two AccountIDs in mssql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to assign every UserID their AccountIDs. So, there are two tables in DB: Users and Accounts.

Users table:

```
UserID    FirstName    LastName    
1         Adam         Barnes      
2         Mike         Radley
```

Accounts table:

```
AccountID    PaymentMethod
1            Card
2            Purse
```

Result should be:

```
UserID    AcountID    PaymentMethod
1         1           Card
1         2           Purse
2         1           Card
2         2           Purse
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a cross join:

```
SELECT
    t1.UserID, t2.AccountID, t2.PaymentMethod
FROM Users t1
CROSS JOIN Accounts t2
ORDER BY
    t1.UserID, t2.AccountID;
```

Your expected results imply that you want to match each user to every type of account.  This is a cartesian product, and cross join is the type of join appropriate for this.